# Wolfram Workbench autocomplete is not working?

Tags: workbench, eclipse

I have installed the latest version of `EclipseIDE` (eclipse-scout-2023-12-R) and latest version of `WolframWorkbench` (WorkbenchUpdate_10.2.43). I have changed the default engine to 13.3 in <kbd>Window</kbd>-><kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Wolfram</kbd>:

[image]

When I open a new .wl file (<kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>Open File...</kbd>)

I don't get autocompletion. I have turned on the autocompletions in <kbd>Window</kbd>-><kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Wolfram</kbd>-><kbd>Editor</kbd>:

[image]

Do I need to create a project or do some configuration to get the autocompletions?